# How add custom dynamic layout in a dialog box?

Tags: android-layout

i am new to android java programming. I am adding a custom dynamic layout to a dialog box. i have 2 classes , Mainactivity.java and Getval.java
The Mainactivity.java create a dialoge and Getval generates dynamic layout at run time. 
Every thing works good but when  it tried to call Getval.java's method, it gives an exception. here is the code of both classes.
The g.setval(); in Mainactivity.java cause problem.

```
                              :::::Mainactivity.java:::::
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Button button;
public Getval g=new Getval();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //set up dialog

            g.setval();
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.attributewin);
            dialog.setTitle("Attribute Window");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();

    }
});

                                   ::::Getval::::
```

public class Getval extends Activity{

```
String names[]={"test","chaeck","kajsdhasj","dlasdig"};
String values[]={"test","chaeck","kajsdhasj","dlasdig"};
String test[]={"Attribut","Value"};
```

public void setval(){

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tly);
```

Button b=new Button(this);

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
//Row
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
//TextViews
    TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
    tv0.setText(names[i]);
    tv0.setMaxWidth(75);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(values[i]);
    tv1.setMaxWidth(150);

    View line = new View(this);
    line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
    line.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

//Setting Views
    tr.addView(tv0);
    tr.addView(tv1);
    tl.addView(tr);
    tl.addView(line);

}
//Button Row
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tr.setGravity(0x11);
    b.setId(100);
    b.setText("Return");
    b.setGravity(0x11);
    tr.addView(b);
    tl.addView(tr);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over this without seeing your xml or complete code (or exception that is thrown), I would be willing to guess that you are trying to inflate/modify a view (R.id.tly) from an activity other than the one where it was originally inflated from (MainActivity).

Generally speaking, you can't do this without doing some tricks with cross activity handlers or other methods.  Perhaps change your code to inflate the views (R.id.tly) in MainActivity (and in your dialog if it is inside of R.layout.attributewin), do your processing in Getval, return them to MainActivity so it can populate the views.

But again, this is just a guess, since I don't see your xml or exception.

Comment: yeah, you are right. That's why i went for making layout programmatic. Thanks for your help!!